# How to design voltage gain circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain

I need to build a circuit with a DC gain of 2 for a 0-5V input, 0-10 V ouput (input will be adjustable). Current can be low since it doesn't really matter (this will be purely as a control signal). Input impedances aren't given.

I'm having trouble getting started. I've read I could use an noninverting amplifier and can choose resistors such that G= 1+R/R2=2, but usually circuits with op amps are for higher gains on small signals right?

So I am not sure how to design / choose components for this circuit. Thanks for the help in advance!

[image: Noninverting Amplifier]

Comment: Try R1 = R2 = 10k Ohm's.

Comment: Yes, 10k is a good sweet spot. Too low and the circuit will waste power, too high and it will be susceptible to noise.

Answer (score 2):

Using an op amp for this is fine. You need to be careful to select the op-amp correctly. The power supply needs to be adequate to provide a 0-10V output some op amps will not drive all the way to the supply rail and some will not properly treat a 0V input if you just have a 0 to +V supply.

R1=R2 and as G36 suggested 10k would be fine for a DC amplifier.

Comment: Thanks! So what’s the process for determining whether rail to rail voltage is reached? Are there certain specs I could just read from the datasheet?  Feel free to point me where I should read!

Comment: You need to look out for output voltage swing, this can be up to a few volts below the supply voltage.

Answer (score 0):

This can also work [edited, using PNP input buffer and level-shifter]. Matching Veb may be required, but the questioner has not yet provided any error requirements or bandwidth goals, or temperature drift or VDD drift issues.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5l9Jy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Original circuit used a 2N3904 (NPN) running at 15v/100K = 150uA, diode connected to shift Vin up to drive base of Q1; the circuit likely would not
have given you Vout = 0, because of the high current.

Comment: That's an interesting topology I haven't seen before! What are its advantages over an op amp? Do any transistors have to be matched for proper performance?

Comment: Would there be a bandwidth requirement if its DC input? Error requirements aren't strict as of yet.

Comment: @ Seth --- do you mean "is this circuit stable"? You should sim it. the R3 node will be very slow.